# C++: How can I perform an operation on every number inside a text file?

Tags: c++

If I have a text file which only has numbers inside. Such as:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

How can I, for example, multiply each number by two and get the result of each individual operation as output to my screen? Would I have to set each number to a variable?

Comment: Have you had a go at doing your homework?

Comment: Try it yourself and show us what you've accomplished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to your problem is to follow these steps:

1. Open a file, and create an int variable ( for instance a)
2. **In Do...while loop** take number from a file like this

Filehandler >> a;

multiply the a like this

```
a = a * 2;
```

or do whatever you want with it.

Print an value

```
cout << a;
```

**till you get EOF**

Of course there is another possibility like storing each value in array and then multiplying it. It depends on you what you will choose.

Comment: If any of answers were helpful, please give us some points. If you still got problem with implementation show us your work.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you. I had an important mid term coming up and was studying some examples from the textbook (not assigned by the professor) and I really wanted to understand what was going on. Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Bluasul Thanks I am really glad that I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know for Loops for example.
you can read the the numbers and store them in an array and use a for loop to multiply or div or whatever and print that .